# Sql Server 2008 R2 Query Optimization

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a Sql Ad-hoc query which is performing badly. Please help me or give me some suggestions to optimize it. Here is the query below:

```
SELECT TOP 20 CustomerPrimaryExtID,
              Max(POSTimeStamp)     AS TransactionDate,
              ExtLocationCode,
              0                     AS RedemptionAmount,
              0                     AS RedemptionCount,
              TerminalNum,
              LogixTransNum,
              POSTransNum           AS TransNum,
              0                     AS DetailRecords,
              CustomerTypeID,
              PresentedCustomerID,
              PresentedCardTypeID,
              HHID,
              Replayed,
              0                     AS TransContext,
              isnull(TransTotal, 0) AS TransTotal
FROM   TransHist AS TH WITH(nolock)
WHERE  ( ( ( CustomerPrimaryExtID IN ( '' )
             AND HHID IS NULL )
            OR HHID = '0000000250000013408'
               AND CustomerTypeID <> 1 )
          OR ( CustomerPrimaryExtID = '0000000250000013408'
               AND CustomerTypeID = 1 ) )
       AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT LogixTransNum
                       FROM   TransRedemptionView AS TR2
                       WHERE  ( ( ( CustomerPrimaryExtID IN ( '' )
                                    AND HHID IS NULL )
                                   OR HHID = '0000000250000013408'
                                      AND CustomerTypeID <> 1 )
                                 OR ( CustomerPrimaryExtID = '0000000250000013408'
                                      AND CustomerTypeID = 1 ) )
                              AND TH.LogixTransNum = TR2.LogixTransNum)
GROUP  BY CustomerPrimaryExtID,
          HHID,
          CustomerTypeID,
          PresentedCustomerID,
          PresentedCardTypeID,
          LogixTransNum,
          POSTransNum,
          TerminalNum,
          ExtLocationCode,
          Replayed,
          TransTotal
ORDER  BY TransactionDate DESC
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe you don't need so many GROUP BY columns, maybe you need just take last 20 transactions... if yes you can use row number or joins.

Comment: How many rows are in these tables?

Comment: Come on 62% of the cost is in a table we know nothing about.  Post the view or convert the query to not use the view.

Answer (score 0):

Given the 62% cost on TransRedemption I would think an index on CustomerPrimaryExtID, HHID, CustomerTypeID and LogixTransNum would help that some.

You could also look at doing:

```
FROM 
    TransHist TH 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    TransRedemption TR2
    ON TH.LogixTransNum = TR2.LogixTransNum
```

Don't use the view in the sub query or the join unless something is being done in that view to limit the number of rows returned from TransRedemption.

Then remove:

```
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT LogixTransNum
                   FROM   TransRedemptionView AS TR2
                   WHERE  ( ( ( CustomerPrimaryExtID IN ( '' )
                                AND HHID IS NULL )
                               OR HHID = '0000000250000013408'
                                  AND CustomerTypeID <> 1 )
                             OR ( CustomerPrimaryExtID = '0000000250000013408'
                                  AND CustomerTypeID = 1 ) )
                          AND TH.LogixTransNum = TR2.LogixTransNum)
```

from the where clause and replace with

```
AND TR2.LogixTransNum IS NULL
```

If TransRedemption has a lot of columns then you may want to limit the results in the join like so:

```
FROM 
    TransHist TH 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
        SELECT 
            LogixTransNum
        FROM
            TransRedemption
    ) TR2
    ON TH.LogixTransNum = TR2.LogixTransNum
```